# Is $c_0$ a $C(K)$ space?

Tags: functional-analysis

Is $c_0$ isomorphic or isometric so $C(K)$ for a countable metric space $K$?

Comment: What's the definition of $C(K)$? Is $K$ supposed to be compact?

Comment: $K$ does not have to be compact

Comment: Then is $C(K)$ supposed to be the Banach space of all *bounded* continuous functions, or what?

Comment: Oh good point. Yes, I suppose $C(K)$ should be all bounded continuous functions on $K$.

Comment: If you are looking at sequences of complex numbers converging to $0$, the supremum norm inherited from $\ell_\infty$ together with the involution given by taking the conjugate of a sequence turns it into an Abelian $C^*$-algebra. You get that  $c_0$is then isomorphic with $C(\hat{c_0})$ (with your notations), where $\hat{c_0}$ is the set of characters of $c_0$. Maybe you can then try and figure out whever or not $\hat{c_0}$ fulfills your hypothesis.

Comment: Actually, if $K$ is a non-compact metric space, then the space of bounded continuous functions on $K$ is not separable.  So $K$ would have to be compact after all.

Comment: Isomorphic: yes.  Isometric: no.

Comment: @G.F Wouldn't the gelfand transform be an isometry from $c_0$ onto $C(\Delta)$ (not just an isomorphism), with $\Delta$ being the maximal ideal space? From GEdgar's response, it would seem then that the maximal ideal space of $c_0$ does not satisfy these conditions

Comment: @user124910: I believe in general, the isometry is onto $C_0(\Delta)$, and $\Delta$ here is just $\mathbb{N}$ again.  You can write $C(\Delta)$ if $\Delta$ is compact, but that only happens if you start with a *unital* algebra.

Comment: @G.F Yes, if $\phi(x)=x$ then $\phi$ is an isometry; we really don't need $C^*$ algebras for _that_.

Comment: Non-isometry follows from the observation that the unit ball of $c_0$ does not have extreme points.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Oh, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question doesn't specify what sort of isomorphism we want.

Also it's not specified exactly what we mean by $C(K)$ if $K$ is not compact. It seems likely that however we interpret $C(K)$ here it contains the constants, hence it cannot be isomorphic to $c_0$ as a complex algebra, since $c_0$ has no identity. Various comments about $C^*$ algebras are wrong, since $c_0$ has no identity; the most we can get from that context is $C_0(K)$, where $K$ is locally compact, and of course that's of no interest since $c_0$ is *equal to* $C_0(\Bbb N)$.

It appears to me that $c_0$ *is* Banach-space-isomorphic to $C(K)$ with $K$ compact. Let $\approx$ denote Banach-space isomorphism.

Let $K=\Bbb N\cup\{\infty\}$ be the one-point compactification of $\Bbb N$. Then $$c_0\approx\{f\in C(K):f(\infty)=0\}:=X,$$so $C(K)\approx \Bbb C\times c_0.$ (Because $(\alpha,f)\mapsto f+\alpha$ gives an isomorphism of $\Bbb C\times X$ onto $C(K)$.)

And $(\alpha,(x_1,x_2,\dots))\mapsto(\alpha,x_1,x_2,\dots)$ shows that $$\Bbb C\times c_0\approx c_0.$$